# Appropriate test to prove hypothesis for given sample

Tags: chi-squared-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

Essentially, I'm writing a research paper, and I have these subjects grouped by their cancer stage from I to IV (ordinal scale) and whether or on they're positive for a specific marker (nominal scale). I am trying to **determine if patients that are marker positive will be more likely to have a higher stage cancer**. I have already done a chi squared test and Mann Whitney U and both have given me a statistically significant p<0.05 value. I'm just not sure which of these two proves my hypothesis, if any. If neither are supposed to answer my question, if anyone could give me a suggestion for a different test, I'd be most appreciative.

[image: Table of samples]

Comment: I'm an engineer, not a stats guy.  If you are looking for a predictive indicator of category, I might suggest you look at Cohen's kappa.  It accounts for sample size, and can handle multiple categories.

Comment: @EngrStudent How does kappa utilize the ordinal information?  I thought kappa was only for nominal data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, no statistical test *proves* a hypothesis. In hypothesis testing, we can reject or fail to reject a null hypothesis. The null is usually something like "nothing is going on" or "there is no relationship" but a) We never accept the null and b) We never prove it is false, we just say that the results we got are unlikely IF it is true.

Second, chi-square just shows that there is evidence of association. It doesn't say which direction it is in (or even if it's in a direction). You have ordinal data so you could use an ordinal method. There are a few such; I like the Jonckheere-Terpstra test, but I don't have strong reasons for that, it just seems more directly ordinal than some others. If you like a different one, fine. Mann Whitney U is fine.

Third, if you think there is some sort of "cause" in the data (i.e. that being at a later stage causes a marker) then you could consider regression.

Comment: The alternative hypothesis for the J-T test is that the medians are strictly ordered, which is not really what is being asked.  What we need is a meaningful quantitative way to express "marker positive [means] more likely to have higher stage cancer." With that in hand, a permutation test ought to be revealing.  To see why this is an issue, plot the data and notice that positive subjects have a strikingly smaller risk of stage II cancer--an empirical U-shaped relationship.